# Unity for Oculus - image effects don't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok, Im building for oculus here with unity and cant get ANY image effects to work with VR. Ive googled around, tried Post Processing AND old legacy image effects, but nothing works. I add them to all the cameras I can find (in OVRCameraRig) - I do the Left, Center, Right, etc.

Yet nothing works - I need a blur effect. If I check and uncheck "Use per eye cameras" in OVR Rig script during runtime, the screen goes stereoscopic (split screen), THEN the image effects work. But it stays in stereoscopic, which I can't have.

What is the problem here?

Comment: why can't you have stereoscopic?

Comment: @zambari because when I put on the headset it doesn't work - it splits the screen in both eyes or something.